# Can't load external SWF dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, flash

The situation that I'm currently stuck on is that I cannot load and display an external swf file in my FlashDevelop project. I normally can do this without a problem, but the issue exists here because someone else coded the file that is loading every class including this one, which loads the swf.

Here is the relevant code in the main class that loads the classes: (I did not write this.)

```
_types = new Vector.<Class>();
_labels = new Vector.<String>();
_types.push(Game1, Game2, Game3, Game4, Game5);
_labels.push("Game1", "Game2", "Game3", "Game4", "Game5");
```

... There are buttons that are then added to the screen which direct you to one of these games. When a button is clicked this function is called:

```
private function menuSelect(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (gameDo[evt.target.name]<2){
            gameDo[evt.target.name] ++;
            cycle++;
        }

        _nextQuest = _types[evt.target.name];
    }
```

The game that I am calling is Game5. When this class is loaded it then attempts to load an external swf file that has the actual game content. Here is the class:

```
package  
{
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
/**
 * ...
 * @author 
 */
public class Game5 extends Sprite implements LoaderMod
{
    private var _loader:Loader;

    public function Game5():void
    {
        _loader = new Loader();
        _loader.load(new URLRequest("Game5.swf"));
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_complete);
    }

    public function loader_complete(evt:Event):void
    {
        var _loadedData:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        _loadedData.addChild(evt.currentTarget.content);
        this.addChild(_loadedData);
    }

}
```

When I run this code, These are the errors that I'm getting:

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot
convert Game5@855b0a1 to Quest.
Fault, onEnterFrame() at Main.as:76
[Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject 
must be a child of the caller.
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
[Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject
must be a child of the caller.
[Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject
must be a child of the caller.
```

And the last four lines in the errors keep generating as the game runs. As for the first two lines in the errors where it says "cannot convert Game5@855b0a1 to Quest" there is another class in the project called Quest.as that is extended by other classes as some sort of super class. The only code that I have written is the Game5.as class here.

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT!

Here is the onEnterFrame() function where the line 76 error is occurring at:

```
70 protected function onEnterFrame(evt:Event):void
71 {
72      if (_nextQuest)
73      {
74          removeChild(mainMenu);
75          removeChild(_menu);
76          _quest = new _nextQuest();
77          addChild(_quest);
78          _nextQuest = null;
79      }
80      if (_quest)
81      {
82          if (! _quest.update())
83          {
84              removeChild(_quest);
85              _quest = null;
86              questions.questions();
87              this.addChild(questions);
88          }
89      }
90  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is _nextQuest typed as Quest? If so, when _nextQuest is being assigned as Game5, since Game5 is not extended from Quest but rather Sprite, you get the first error. You can fix this by changing the type of _nextQuest to Sprite. I'm not sure what Quest.as extends or does, so I can't really give any advice on that.

As for the other errors, are you given a line where they occur? That can be helpful to find the exact problem, but it looks like "removeChild()" is being called on something that has not been added. That is when I most commonly receive that error.

Edit: Looks like your URL to the loaded file is not being found. Check to make sure that is right in relation to the swf, that it isn't in any directories or up a level.

Comment: The _nextQuest variable is of type Class, and is by default set to null until a button is clicked the the menuSelect function fires. How would I change the type of _nextQuest to Sprite if it's looking for a Class type object? I tried this and I got the error "Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:Sprite to an unrelated type Class." As for a line, this is a direct copy+paste from the output panel, so no there are no other line numbers to help me here. And where did you see removeChild() at?

Comment: I was using removeChild as an example from my experience of something that could possibly be causing the "must be child of caller" errors, but without more information, it is mostly a guess. However, it does look like an error is occurring in Main.as at line 76. 

Perhaps the first error involving Quest has nothing to do with _nextQuest then. There must be some other place where Game5 is trying to be used where type Quest should be used instead. 

I noticed that the Game objects are in a vector of Class. However, it is adding Game5, which is of type Sprite. Try using an array instead.

Comment: I will try that. I'll add the function that is at line 76 to the question in case it might clear things up.

Comment: Alright, from what I can see, _quest, which is type Quest I will assume, is trying to create a new (whatever _nextQuest holds). _nextQuest is assigned as Game5, so therefore _quest:Quest = new Game5(); Your error is probably coming from _quest trying to be assigned a value of type Game5 when it is looking for a type of Quest.

Comment: Okay, i see what you mean. I probably should have mentioned this already, but the class itself loads just fine as long as I don't try to load a swf from the class. Would this explain that as well?

Comment: Interesting.. I threw in a ProgressEvent method to see if the swf is even loading and I out of bytesLoaded and bytesTotal I got 1002/1002 as a result. So the swf is in fact loading! But I'm still not seeing it for whatever reason.